# Regex that finds a line with exactly 3 words in it

Tags: grep

I have a problem that requires me to write a regex that  finds a line that containing exactly 3 groups of characters (it could be words or numbers)  and that  ends with another specific word.  The way I had in mind was to find a pattern that ended in a space, and look for it 3 times.  assuming this is the correct way to go about it, I do no know how to find a space, but I thought it would look like **.*"find a space"{3} endword$**.  Is this the way it would be done?  Even if it is not the way to do it how do you find a space?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by three groups of words you would accept *any* non-space character, you could write:

```
/^\s*(?:\S+\s+){3}endword$/
```

The initial caret is to make sure you have *exactly* 3 non-space groups on the line.

Of course you need to consider whether things like control characters could appear, and adjust accordingly.

Comment: the initial caret makes sure a character is present to start,  I get that part. but the (?:S+\s+) is the part I do not understand?  Can you explain what it means?

Comment: `\S` is any _nonspace_ character, `s` is any space character. When something is in `(?:)` it makes it a non-capturing group.  Expand things out and you will get `/^\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+endword$/` which is a string starting with zero or more spaces, then three words separated by spaces, then some spaces then the fourth word, which is "endword."

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your flavor, something like the below would do it:

```
\b+.+?\b+.+?\b+.+?\bendword$
```

This makes use of the word boundary mark (`\b`) and non-greedy repetitions (`+?`), so it may be slightly different in your specific implementation, especially if you're using something old like `grep`.